# iterate over pandas columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

want to calculate C based on values of count, A and B

sample df:

| count | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 23 | 2 | nan |
| nan | 23 | 1 | nan |
| yes | 41 | 6 | nan |

result I want

| count | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 23 | 2 | 46 |
| nan | 23 | 1 | 0 |
| yes | 41 | 6 | 246 |

calculate C = A*B only when count value = yes otherwise C values =0
that is, it should skip nan values of count

Any help is appreciable

I am trying this

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['count'] == 'yes':
        df.loc[ ind, 'C'] =row['A'] *row['B']
    else:
        df.loc[ ind, 'C'] =0
```

But it's giving error : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas overloads `*` for this operation, provided you correctly specify the indices you want to set:

```
mask = df["count"].notna()
df.loc[mask, "C"] = df["A"]*df["B"]
df.C.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

or a slightly more concise version that would annoy your coworkers:

```
df["C"] = df["A"]*df["B"]*(df["count"].notna())
```

In the last, `df["count"].notna()` returns a boolean column, which is converted to a numeric type when multiplied by numerical columns.  Concise but as clear.

output for either:

```
  count   A  B      C
0   yes  23  2   46.0
1   NaN  23  1      0
2   yes  41  6  246.0
```

This will be more performant than `.apply` and *much* more performant than iterrows.

Comment: the condition wasn't applied

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
df.C = df.A.mul(df.B).where(df['count'].eq('yes')).fillna(0)

df
#  count   A  B      C
#0   yes  23  2   46.0
#1   NaN  23  1    0.0
#2   yes  41  6  246.0
```

Or if you prefer operators: `df.C = (df.A * df.B).where(df['count'] == 'yes').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:-

```
df['C']=df[df['count']=='yes']['C'].fillna(value=df['A']*df['B'])
df['C']=df['C'].fillna(0)
```

Try this:-

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['count'] == 'yes':
        df.loc[ ind, 'C'] =row['A'] *row['B']
    else:
        df.loc[ ind, 'C'] =0
```

You are getting error because you write `df['count']=='yes'` instead of `row['count'] == 'yes'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with [`df.prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) to multiply `A` with `B` and mask `NaN` values using [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

```
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].prod(axis=1).mask(df['count'].isna(), 0)

  count   A  B    C
0   yes  23  2   46
1   NaN  23  1    0
2   yes  41  6  246
```